# Проблема в Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node-modules

Помогите пожалуйста, консоль выдаёт ошибку :(

**pakage.json**

```
{
  "name": "thrivetalk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.51.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.10"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 version",
    "not IE 11",
    "maintained node versions"
  ]
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
import imagemin from ('gulp-imagemin');
var htmlmin = require('htmlmin');

gulp.task('server', function() {
    
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "dist"
        }
    });

});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/sass/**/*.+(scss|sass)")
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(rename({
                prefix: "",
                suffix: ".min"
              }))
            .pipe(autoprefixer())
            .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/css"))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.+(scss|sass|css)", gulp.parallel('styles'));
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on("change", gulp.parallel('html'));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/*.html")
        .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/"));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/js/**/*.js")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js"));
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/fonts/**/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/fonts"));
});

gulp.task('icons', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/icons/**/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/icons"));
});

gulp.task('mailer', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/mailer/**/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/mailer"));
});

gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src("src/img/**/*")
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/img"));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch', 'server', 'styles', 'scripts', 'fonts', 'icons', 'mailer', 'images', 'html'));
```

**console**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:117:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:70:21)
```

Comment: скорее всего ругается на `import imagemin from ('gulp-imagemin');` попробуйте заменить его на `const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');`

Comment: Решил проблему, всё дело в image-min, та версия которая у меня была она стала поддерживать новый формат где нужно использовать import и from. Просто установите версию 7.0 или какая то такая  уже не помню точно и потом пишите const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'); или что-то подобное